# Retrieve related objects in DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.7.1 CBV's. I am trying to retrieve a related objects of `projects` so i can get FK `client_name` like this:

```
<li>{{ project.client_set.get.client_name }}</li>
```

My `projects.models` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

from clients.models import Client


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    account_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My DetailView `projects.views` looks like so:

```
class ProjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "projects/project_details.html"
    model = Project
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project has a direct ForeignKey to Client, not a reverse relationship. So you can access it using the field you have defined:

```
{{ object.client.client_name }}
```

Comment: I did that as well and all I get is `maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__`

Comment: Got it, I had an old deprecated managers.py class laying around causing recursionj issues, thanks Daniel